# Seq.zip in F# may require seemingly extra sequence element to complete

Tags: haskell, f#

Let's Seq.zip two F# sequences, one represented by a list and the other - by Seq.filter applied to an infinite sequence:

```
Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i)
|> Seq.filter ((>) 3)
|> Seq.zip ["A";"B"]
```

returns as expected

```
val it : seq<string * int> = seq [("A", 0); ("B", 1)]
```

However,

```
Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i)
|> Seq.filter ((>) 2)
|> Seq.zip ["A";"B"]
```

hangs on trying to get non-existing 3rd member that can pass Seq.filter and eventually blows up fsi:

```
 Error: Enumeration based on System.Int32 exceeded System.Int32.MaxValue.
```

although the other argument represented by list of letters hints that just two filtered elements would be enough to perform zip to the function specification.

If we turn to Haskell for implementation comparison the equivalent

```
 zip ["A","B"] (filter (<2) [0..])
```

completes without any problem yielding

```
[("A",0),("B",1)]
```

As Haskell implementation behavior seem intuitively right what is the justification for the observed behavior of F# Seq.zip implementation?

UPDATE:

I did not notice that Haskell

```
zip (filter (<2) [0..]) ["A","B"]
```

does not complete similarly to F#.

**Bottom line:** It is impossible to implement Zip function capable of zipping sequences of defined and undefined lengths in argument order-agnostic manner. F# Zip implementation simply prefers invariant to argument order behavior over Haskell argument order dependent one.

Comment: 11 years later. Not sure this function was available back then, but `Seq.takeWhile` and variants will _not_ exhibit this problem, as they simply stop trying to find the next item once the condition turns false. This won't be useful for all cases, but in the example given here, it would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't hang in Haskell is because the implementation of `zip` just so happens to be stricter in it's first argument than in it's second.

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b) : zip as bs
zip _      _      = []
```

Since the patterns are checked from left to right, this gives the following behavior.

```
*Main> zip [] undefined
[]
*Main> zip undefined []
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Since `filter (<2) [0..]` is semantically equivalent to `0 : 1 : ⊥`, your example is after two iterations

```
("A", 0) : ("B", 1) : zip [] undefined =
("A", 0) : ("B", 1) : []
```

If we change the order of the arguments to `zip (filter (<2) [0..]) ["A", "B"]`, we get

```
(0, "A") : (1, "B") : zip undefined [] =
(0, "A") : (1, "B") : undefined
```

I don't know much about F#, but I suspect something similar is happening there.

Note that there is no way to define `zip` such that `zip [] undefined` and `zip undefined []` both return `[]`, since you have to check one of the arguments first, and it's impossible to check against ⊥ due to [monotonicity](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics#Monotonicity).

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, perhaps http://conal.net/blog/posts/lazier-function-definitions-by-merging-partial-values would be of interest.

Comment: @kvb: Good find! Note that `unamb` has to "cheat" using `unsafePerformIO` to accomplish this.

Comment: @hammar: Bad me was to miss checking the other order of arguments. Summing up: as long as we do not deviate from sequential execution paradigm it is impossible to implement Zip function capable of zipping sequences of defined and undefined lengths in argument order-agnostic manner. F# Zip implementation simply prefers consistent argument order invariant behavior over Haskell argument order dependent one.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how Haskell does it, and I do agree that it seems intuitively correct (except I wonder what would happen in Haskell if you switched the fixed length list and the indeterminate length list), but I can show you *why* it works this way in F#. You can see in the F# source code file [seq.fs](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64420#1113981) that the significant implementation detail is in `IEnumerable.map2`:

```
  let map2 f (e1 : IEnumerator<_>) (e2 : IEnumerator<_>) : IEnumerator<_>=
      upcast 
          {  new MapEnumerator<_>() with
                 member this.DoMoveNext curr = 
                    let n1 = e1.MoveNext()
                    let n2 = e2.MoveNext()
                    if n1 && n2 then
                       curr <- f e1.Current e2.Current
                       true
                    else 
                       false
                 member this.Dispose() = e1.Dispose(); e2.Dispose()
          }
```

So `Seq.zip` will try to move both sequences to their third element before deciding whether the zip is complete, thus `Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i) |> Seq.filter ((>) 2)` gets stuck trying to find the third element "forever" (until `Error: Enumeration based on System.Int32 exceeded System.Int32.MaxValue`).

Comment: Seems to be a different version of the source to what I used, but interestingly if it was changed to `if e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext` it would work half the time (finite sequence was e1)

Comment: @jpalmer - yeah, I noticed a lot of people linking to the github source these days, but that is for the Mono port of F#, since I work in Windows, I look at the original codeplex source.

Comment: @jpalmer - yep, that would do the trick. but I tend to believe the F# designers deliberately chose the currently implementation, since it would be a somewhat surprising implementation detail for the order of the arguments to `Seq.zip` to change it's behavior.

Comment: @Stephen Swensen: Maybe the word "justification" in the original question wasn't the best to use, but I did already knew details of F# implementation from reading the source. My initial (wrong) assumption was that Haskell implementation is invariant to the order of arguments :(

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Swensen has already answered the question.

The solution as of now seems to use Seq.take as you know the length of one of the sequences.

```
Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i)
|> Seq.filter ((>) 2)
|> Seq.zip ["A";"B"]
|> Seq.take 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the source (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs at about line 900) this is what happens:

The relevant function is in Seq.fs and called revamp2 (this is what is called by Seq.zip)

```
let revamp2 f (ie1 : seq<_>) (source2 : seq<_>) =
        mkSeq (fun () -> f (ie1.GetEnumerator()) (source2.GetEnumerator()))
```

Now when we call .MoveNext() on the sequence returned by this it calls MoveNext() on BOTH of the input sequences.

Doing it in this way has made much of the other code simpler but has caused your problem - .MoveNext() will not return for the filtered infinite sequence, but will return for the finite sequence, leading to an infinite loop.